# Parallax navigation and more than one tabeview [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, parallax

I want to do a screen having sticky parallax header (navigation) and more than one table view as pages with segment control. I found two perfect custom controls but unfortunately I didn't know how to combine them in one screen.

[YSLContainerViewController](https://github.com/y-hryk/YSLContainerViewController)

[DTTableView](https://github.com/toandk/DTTableView)

Anybody can help, please?

Comment: Parallax header is header section of tableview. So according to my thinking if you set one table's header as parallax view then it will set all tableview's header as parallax

Comment: @JeckyModi So any hint to proceed?